# How to use two English language string files in Android(like UK, US english),

Tags: android, string, local

I need to implement two different string files but same language.
I have tried en-rUS and en but it's not working.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Please explain what kind of problem you are trying to solve, not how you trying to solve it.

Comment: well... you need to do but... what external factor that's stopping you? fights for your dreams BRO!!

Comment: I suspect you are doing something like `strings-en-rUS.xml`, but you have to create folder `values-en-rUS` and put your `strings.xml` in there. Easier way is to just right-click in project navigator and choose `New -> Android Resource Directory`

Answer (score 2):

String files are just kind of value resource files and you can create as many as you like as long as:

1. it's located in `res->values->filename` folder
2. has `<resources>` root element
3. and contains `<string name="string_resource_name">string_value</string>` in it.

There's not naming constraint so you can organize your strings into different files, e.g.: `names.xml`, `warnings.xml` and ...